# How can I type wider range of LaTeX characters in the IPython REPL

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

This question is specific about the IPython REPL, not the Jupyter notebook.

Currently according to the [docs on forward latex completion](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.completer.html#forward-latex-unicode-completion):

> Only valid Python identifiers will complete

Which means that, by default, I can type β by typing `\beta` and hitting tab, but I can't type ∇ by the same method.

Is there a way to type other unicode characters like ∇ in the IPython REPL? Maybe with an extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can type other unicode characters like ∇ in IPython REPL by using the unicode escape sequence "\u" followed by the unicode code point in hexadecimal.

In this case

```
print("\u2207")

∇
```